# Jquery full calendar not Renderering

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I have the below code to render events to Jquery Full calendar..

the code returns the events as object but i don't know how to render the events..Pease help me to sort out...

```
  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/xtest.aspx")%>';
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 theme: true,
 color: 'red',
 header: { left: 'prev,next', center: 'today,title', right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month' },
 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pageUrl+"/GetEvents",
            data: '{Start: "' + start + '",End: "' + end + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
            callback(response.d);
            }
        });
        }
   }); 
});
<script>
```

/GetEvents returns like below..

```
[
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2014-09-01'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: '2014-09-07',
                end: '2014-09-10'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-09-09T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                id: 999,
                title: 'Repeating Event',
                start: '2014-09-16T16:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Conference',
                start: '2014-09-11',
                end: '2014-09-13'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-09-12T10:30:00',
                end: '2014-09-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Lunch',
                start: '2014-09-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Meeting',
                start: '2014-09-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Happy Hour',
                start: '2014-09-12T17:30:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dinner',
                start: '2014-09-12T20:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Birthday Party',
                start: '2014-09-13T07:00:00'
            },
            {
                title: 'Click for Google',
                url: 'http://google.com/',
                start: '2014-09-28'
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Instead of using `events` as a function, why don't you use it as a json feed like this: `events: pageUrl+"/GetEvents"`?

Comment: I want to render the events by monthwise..on month change the function runs and get the events of that particular month only..

Comment: Then why don't you use ` defaultView: 'month'` and remove `agendaDay,agendaWeek` from `header: { right: '...'}` ?

Comment: Why are you "returning" response.d instead of response?